# How to find element within fieldset with no class or id

Tags: capybara

I have two field-set on my page. None of them have any id or class.
Now i want to fill specific field in second field-set.

Currently i a doing something like this which is not working:

```
within_fieldset('fieldset') do
  fill_in 'app_answers_attributes_0_answer', with: 'My First Answer'
end
click_on 'Submit'
```

And it is giving error:

> Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find fieldset "fieldset"

Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`within_fieldset` takes the id or legend text of the fieldset - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Session#within_fieldset-instance_method - so it's not really surprising `within_fieldset('fieldset')` isn't working for you.  How you can do what you want really depends on how you're HTML is structured.  For instance if you're fieldsets have legends

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Something</legened>
  ...
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Other thing</legened>
  ...
</fieldset>
```

You can do

```
within_fieldset('Other thing') do
    ...
end
```

If you don't have legends, but have wrapping elements

```
<div id="first_section">
   ...
    <fieldset>...</fieldset>
<div>
<div id="second_section">
    <fieldset>...</fieldset>
</div>
```

then you can just scope using CSS to the correct fieldset

```
within('#second_section fieldset') do
   ...
end
```

If instead the fieldsets are siblings

```
<div>
  <fieldset>...</fieldset>
  <fieldset>...</fieldset>
</div>
```

then you can just scope to the second fieldset with a CSS sibling selector

```
within("fieldset + fieldset") do
  ...
end
```